# permission error while trying to get all writable directories vb.net

Tags: vb.net, permissions, directory

I have this function which suppose to return all the writable paths in a given directory

```
    Private Function getAllFolders(ByVal directory As String) As String()

    Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
    Dim path() As String = {}
    For Each subfolder As IO.DirectoryInfo In fi.GetDirectories()
        Dim Attributes As System.IO.FileAttributes = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(subfolder.ToString).Attributes
        If (Attributes And IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly) <> 0 Then
            Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
            path(path.Length - 1) = subfolder.FullName
            For Each s As String In getAllFolders(subfolder.FullName)
                Dim SubAttributes As System.IO.FileAttributes = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(s.ToString).Attributes
                If (SubAttributes And IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly) <> 0 Then
                    Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
                    path(path.Length - 1) = s
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return path
End Function
```

Seems there is some wrong dealing with permissions issue, I keep getting "UnauthorizedAccessException was handled" when trying to debug the code, any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the value of _directory_? It is normal that some directory listed by GetDirectories give back UnauthorizedAccessExceptio to your program. Try, for example, to open the _C:\System Volume Information_ using the File Explorer

Comment: It could be any folder or drive I tried every drive and avoided to try system drive(c), if you wonder I'm starting from accessible directory @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some system folders such as "Documents and Settings" or "System Volume Information" will generate that error. You can test `fi` to make sure it's not a system folder before the `for` loop. If the offending directory has some other attribute causing the problem, you can check that attribute in addition to FileAttributes.System.

```
If (fi.Attributes And FileAttributes.System) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Error stopped rising but no paths are returned seems like it starts  the for loop from a system folder and stops, so still not working with a given drive letter
@xpda

Comment: Single step through the loop and check the name of directory fi. That will tell you which folder is causing the problem.